# R Studio - App designing with Shiny package - getting stuck at listening to port

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

Greeting to all...!

I have an issue with Shiny app designing in Rstudio.

The below is code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = “Basic Dashboard”, 
dropdownMenuOutput("MessageMenu")),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dash 
board")), 
      menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
           )
              ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(# First tab content 
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard", fluidRow(box(plotOutput("plot1", height 
= 250)), box(title = "Controls",
  sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1,100,50)))), 
        #Second tab content
  tabItem(tabName = "widgets", h2("Widgets tab content"))))
server <- function(input, output) {
set.seed(123)
histdata <- rnorm(500)
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
hist(data)
 })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

With the above code I saved file.
When I open that r file to run the app it throwing error:
**Error in parse(file, keep.source = FALSE, srcfile = src, encoding = enc) : 
  C:/Users/velumani_d/Documents/sankar/shiny/Dashboard.R:18:3: unexpected symbol
17:

18:   server
      ^
Possible missing comma at:
18:  server <- function(input, output) {
     ^
Error in sourceUTF8(fullpath, envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())) : 
  Error sourcing C:\Users\VELUMA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGCsHzx\filee181233354**

I am not able to understand why this error comes in while running the saved R file again.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhnmJ.png)
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you completely, but what you should be doing is writing your code in a script. In RStudio, go to File, New File, R Script. Write your code there, save it and run.

Comment: Not sure to understand as well. Your app renders nothing (a white window, in other words, or the default rendering of the dashboard). And while the app is running, it's normal that the R console is not available for writing code.